# Malloc error when defining stringstream as member in header

Tags: c++

So I had this class:

```
/** Controller.h before editing **/
namespace base
{

    class Controller
    {
        private:
            std::string* errorText;
            std::string fileIdentifier;

            bool isFileIdentifierSet;
            bool isFileChecked;
            bool isFileParsed;
            bool isNddlGenerated;
        public:
            /** public stuff... **/
    }
}
```

The implementation of this class worked so far, but then I had to use a library, which was producing a lot of cerr output, but since this is a CLI program, I wanted to catch the error texts and display them the way I want. So I searched SO for cerr suppression, and found a lot of good hints, which I wanted to implement then. Please note, that the program did work after I added the library, I was just unsatisfied with the error outputs the library produced. So this is the updated version of the class above:

```
/** Controller.h after editing **/
namespace base
{

    class Controller
    {
        private:
            std::stringstream cerrOvRdBuf; /** new **/ /** error **/
            std::streambuf* cerrStdRdBuf; /** new **/

            std::string* errorText;
            std::string fileIdentifier;

            bool isFileIdentifierSet;
            bool isFileChecked;
            bool isFileParsed;
            bool isNddlGenerated;

            void disableCerr(); /** new **/
            void enableCerr(); /** new **/
            std::string getBufferedCerrOutput(); /** new **/
        public:
            /** public stuff... **/
    }
}
```

The implementation of the functions is like this:

```
/** Implementation of new functions in Controller.cpp **/
void Controller::disableCerr()
{
    std::cerr.rdbuf(this->cerrOvRdBuf.rdbuf());
}

void Controller::enableCerr()
{
    std::cerr.rdbuf(this->cerrStdRdBuf);
}

string Controller::getBufferedCerrOutput()
{
    return this->cerrOvRdBuf.str();
}
```

However, even if I don't even use any of the functions, the program was crashing with this output:

```
nddl-generator-cli: malloc.c:2373: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I then proceeded to remove everything until I saw what exactly caused the error, and in the end I surprisingly found out, that the error happens as soon as I define the private member `std::stringstream cerrOvRdBuf;` (I marked the definition above with the comment `/** error **/`) in `Controller.h`.
What is causing the problems? I can't imagine that a simple member definition causes the program to crash?

My intention was to use the functions as soon as I make a library call, like so:

```
/** inside any function of Controller.cpp **/
this->disableCerr();
/** any library call **/
this->enableCerr();
string errorFromLib = this->getBufferedCerrOutput();
/** go on normally, print erros the way I want, etc... **/
```

To sum it up, this is the minimum change I have to make to the `Controller.h` (and nothing in `Controller.cpp`) to reproduce the crash:

```
/** Controller.h with minimum changes producing the error **/
namespace base
{

    class Controller
    {
        private:
            std::stringstream cerrOvRdBuf; /** new **/ /** error **/

            std::string* errorText;
            std::string fileIdentifier;

            bool isFileIdentifierSet;
            bool isFileChecked;
            bool isFileParsed;
            bool isNddlGenerated;

            /** please note that the functions are not even defined or implemented here **/
        public:
            /** public stuff... **/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream) as a class member is perfectly valid. Usually, when you add a new member and have some mysterious errors or crashes, this results from the need to recompile a dependant source. Try doing a `make clean` and then rebuild everything.

---

Apart from that, you must save the old stream buffer, otherwise you cannot restore it later. Change

```
void Controller::disableCerr()
{
    std::cerr.rdbuf(this->cerrOvRdBuf.rdbuf());
}
```

to

```
void Controller::disableCerr()
{
    cerrStdRdBuf = std::cerr.rdbuf(this->cerrOvRdBuf.rdbuf());
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks I didn't notice. But anyway, this doesn't solve the problem, since, like I told in the OP, the error even occurs if I change nothing but the member definition of the stringstream

Comment: Your edit solved the problem.... I thought eclipse would recompile everything, but now I know better. Thank you very much!